# Как правильно в данном случае поступить с функцией, как при вызове функции пропускать параметры

Tags: javascript

Есть задача. Написать функцию, которая принимает время (часы, минуты, секунды) и выводит его на экран в формате «чч:мм:сс».
Если при вызове функции минуты и/или секунды не были переданы, то выводить их как 00.
Я сделал(но не правильно) её так
Но когда я хочу вызвать функцию пропустив параметр в данном случае b,  то получается такой синтаксис что между двумя другими параметрами стоят две запятые. Как в данном случае правильно вызвать функцию что бы можно было указать часы(a) и секунды(c) не указывая минуты(b)

```js
function timeStr(a,b,c){
    if ( c == undefined) {
        let str = `${a}:${b}:00`;
        return str;
    }
    else if ( b == undefined) {
        let str = `${a}:00:${0}`;
        return str;
    }
    else {
let arr = [a, b, c];
let str = arr.join(':');
return str;
} 
}
alert(timeStr(24,,23));
```

Comment: пропускать параметры нельзя.

Comment: Пфф function(...args) { if(args.length === 3) {тут с стремя} if(arts.length === 2) {тут с двумя}}

Comment: @ДенисСтепанов, _тут с двумя_ - но с какими двумя? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, да согласен, что-то упустил момент, что секунды опускают, ну а почему бы не передать обьект. C:

Comment: @ДенисСтепанов, здесь все от постановки вопроса записит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function setTime(h) {
  return function setMinutes(m = 0) {
    return function setSeconds(s = 0) {
      return `${h}:${m}:${s}`
    }
  }
}

var time = setTime(22)()(16);
console.log(time);
```

со стрелочными функциями может выглядит чуть чуть опрятнее:

```js
const setTime = h => {
  return (m = 0) => {
    return (s = 0) => {
      return `${h}:${m}:${s}`
    }
  }
}

var time = setTime(22)()();
console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

А если передать время в функцию как строку, а потом разбить ее на массив по запятым, проверить каждый элемент и если он пустой, то меняем его на '00', и потом обратно массив загоняем в строку.

```js
function timeStr(t){
  t=t.split(',').map(i=>!i?'00':i);
  return t.join(':');
}
alert(timeStr('24,,23'));
```

Answer (score 0):

А пусть будет один объект в качестве аргумента... вместо 3-х чисел)

```js
let time = {h: 5, s: 7};

console.log( timeStr( time ) );

function timeStr(obj){
  return [
    ( addZero( obj.h ) || "00" ),
    ( addZero( obj.m ) || "00" ),
    ( addZero( obj.s ) || "00" ),
  ].join(":");
}

function addZero(n){
  if( !isNaN(n) ){
    return n > 9 ? n : "0" + n;
  }
}
```

Сразу создается массив. Каждый его элемент взят в скобки, чтобы в итоге туда попал правильный результат вычислений: Попытка достать число из объекта по соответствующему ключу. Если его там нет и вернулось undefined ( уже в результате функции addZero )- для такого случая предусмотрено ИЛИ `|| "00"`.